# how to transform HTML to Regex

Tags: html, regex, transform

I will extract from href="download.php?id=469979" this "OutDaughtered.S02E03.A.Quint.In.Crisis.720p.TLC.WEBRip.AAC2.0.x264-BTW.torrent"

```
<a class="index" href="download.php?id=469979"><img src="styles/images/download.png" style="position:relative;bottom:1px;" alt="Download" border="0"> OutDaughtered.S02E03.A.Quint.In.Crisis.720p.TLC.WEBRip.AAC2.0.x264-BTW.torrent</a>
```

i have this code:

```
# Search for filename
my $match_filename=qr/<a class="index" href="download.php\/.*?\/.*?.torrent"><font color=.*?>(.*?).torrent<\/font><\/a> .Press/ms;
my $filename_matches=$r->match('filename', $match_filename);
if($filename_matches==0){ $r->err('Can not continue without filename, aborting!'); return 0;}
my $filename=@$filename_matches[0];
$r->err("Filename: $filename");
```

i have this error:

```
Failed to match filename
Can not continue without filename, aborting!
```

thanks

Comment: Say what now? What is it you want to do, WHY do you want to do it, and what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. What do you mean by "transform html to a regex"? Regular expression are a _search_ pattern, html is markup code. They have nothing in common. You cannot "transform" them into each other.

Comment: Maybe you want the regex that can match that code? Explain please.

Comment: `.*` will transform **any** HTML, **any** text.... **anything** !

Comment: i will extract from  " href="download.php?id=469979""   this  OutDaughtered.S02E03.A.Quint.In.Crisis.720p.TLC.WEBRip.AAC2.0.x264-BTW.torrent

Comment: and i will extract this .torrent file from this href="download.php?id=469979"

Answer (score 0):

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=">\s)(?:.*)(?=<)/m';
$str = '<a class="index" href="download.php?id=469979"><img src="styles/images/download.png" style="position:relative;bottom:1px;" alt="Download" border="0"> OutDaughtered.S02E03.A.Quint.In.Crisis.720p.TLC.WEBRip.AAC2.0.x264-BTW.torrent</a>
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**REGEXP:**

```
/(?<=">\s)(?:.*)(?=<)/m
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => OutDaughtered.S02E03.A.Quint.In.Crisis.720p.TLC.WEBRip.AAC2.0.x264-BTW.torrent
        )

)
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/vYGgJz/1

Comment: and i will extract this .torrent file from this href="download.php?id=469979"

Comment: it will extract text without tags.